# Element focuses when I click far away from it - is this correct?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've created a test case in which an element with `display: inline;` gets focused even when I don't click it directly and element with `display: block;` doesn't get focused that way.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open http://jsfiddle.net/xkfH6/1/
2. Click "Test 1" container.
3. Click anywhere else.

**Expected result:** When any white space or the green area are clicked "Test 2" won't be focused. "Test 2" should be focused only when it's clicked directly.

**Actual result:** "Test 2" gets focused even if mouse clicks some distant area not related to that container. It doesn't happen with "Test 1" though and "Test 1" behaves as expected in my opinion.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if I can make the "Test 2" container not focus when mouse doesn't click it directly?

Update: This happens in Chrome 35 only and not in Firefox 30.

Comment: You forgot the JS part in your JSFidle ;)

Comment: Firefox does not behave the way your "green text" explains it should. I only see "Test 2" get focus when I click directly on it.

Comment: @Jenova70 I tagged it with "javascript" because the answer will most likely require it but the demo code is correct. It shouldn't contain JavaScript. Pure HTML/CSS behave like that for me in Chrome 35.

Comment: I get the same that Pointy gets. FF30 here and it behaves exactly as it should. Perhaps something else like a developer extension is causing this? Did you try restarting the browser?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xkfH6/1/ if i put another element after Test 2, it works fine

Comment: @florin.prisecariu Yes, but only for the area below "Test 2". Clicking the green area will still focus "Test 2".

Comment: try `-webkit-user-select: none` and `-moz-user-select: none` on the css of the Test2 element. Might be a quick fix.

Comment: do not put negative z-index for .area... z-index: 10; works fine

Comment: @florin.prisecariu Imagine that this area is not there (or delete it before testing). It's for presentational purposes only and that's why it has negative `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the div containing Test2 as follows :

```
<div>
    <a><div contenteditable="true">Test 2</div></a>
</div>
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/hs8Dx/)

Comment: Yes, that works but I need `contenteditable` on the link. Otherwise someone may delete that link and this particular place must always have just a single link with editable text. Placing `contenteditable` on a DIV will enable users to create paragraphs etc.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Simply try putting the editable div inside the "a" tag.

Comment: Thank you! If I manually strip paragraphs then this solution will work. After seeing it work in other browsers I started to think that it's just Chrome bug/feature and perhaps it should be left that way and it's best to let Chrome developers decide if they are going to change this in the future or not.